# Format dates inside array, implode and insert into database

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am imploding various arrays and then inserting them into a database to then later retrieve them and explode them into their original arrays. I want to do this with an array of dates but I need to format them before inserting.

How can I format the dates in the array and then pass it to the `implode()` function to insert it into the database? Similarly I will need to explode it an reformat the array upon retrieval.

The structure of the array is very simple

```
$array = (
           [0] => 02/09/2013
           [1] => 29/03/2012
           [2] => 13/12/2010
         )
```

I am guessing it will require a foreach loop to cycle through it and format each date but how can I return the formatted array to then pass it to implode?

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary? And show what a final string should look like? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Necessary because I want to save an indefinite amount of dates in a single row in my table. I have tried formatting the whole array with date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you could use a `foreach`

```
<?php
$arr = array(0 => '02/09/2013',1 => '29/03/2012',2 => '13/12/2010'); 
foreach($arr as &$val)
{
    $val = date('d.m.y',strtotime($val)); //<--- Write your own format.
}
echo implode(',',$arr); //<--- Implode the array using your seperator.
```

Comment: So I can access the formatted array from its original variable name after the foreach loop? Excellent thank you!

Comment: Yeah but note I have passed `&` before the `$val` :) **Passing by reference**

Comment: Yea I noticed that. I haven't seen it before so I'll have to read about it. Thank you very much, worked a treat.